# How to get the value of a javascript object?

Tags: php, javascript

I have an object and inside that object are further objects. I want to get the value of those objects. Thanks!

```
      foreach($query as $row){
        $vehicles[$row->deviceID] = Array(
            'description' => $row->description,
            'deviceID' => $row->deviceID
        ); 
      }
```

and then I pass it to the view and stored it to a global javascript variable.

```
      var vehicleList = <?php echo $vehicleList; ?>;
```

here is the output of my console.log if I type vehicleList in my console log in chrome:

```
vehicleList

>Object
  >11292: Object
    description: "Bus 1"
  >11293: Object
    description: "Bus 2"
  >11294: Object
    description: "Bus 1"
```

The value I want to get is the description.
Is it also possible to store another value to the object 11292? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the script that creates the object?

Comment: I am creating the objects from the controller and passing it to the javascript.

$vehicles[$row->deviceID] = Array(
                'description' => $row->description,
            ); 

and then I pass it to the javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(vehicleList["11292"]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to add additional values to the object? I can get the value now by using this in the javascript vehicleList[this.id]. Thanks again!

Comment: @jovenrp: Just do something like `vehicleList["myProperty"] = someVariable` and you're set to go!

Comment: ooooooooohhhhhh! damn! im using $.extend function. hahaha! I didn't noticed that! hahaha Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To access a property of an object, use the syntax `object.property`. Examples include `myArray.length`, `document.body`, `window.name` and so on.

In this case, however, the property names are numbers (more specifically they start with numbers - it's okay to have numbers in the middle), so you need to use `[]` notation instead. This works just like `.` notation, except the property name is given as a string. Examples: `object["property"]`, `myArray["length"]`, `document["body"]`, `window["name"]`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to add additional values to the object?
I can get the value now by using this in the javascript vehicleList[this.id]. Thanks again!